# Why are there extra values in an array?

Tags: java, arrays

My code is here:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Q1102 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String temp = "1 3 5 7 6";
        int[] array1 = new int[temp.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length(); i += 2) {
            int mounth = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(temp.charAt(i)));
            array1[i] = mounth;
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array1));
    }
}
```

For some strange reason, the program outputs this:

```
[1, 0, 3, 0, 5, 0, 7, 0, 6]
```

Can someone please tell me why this occurs, and how to remove the extra zeros?

I've printed out the values that entered the array as they are entered, and there aren't any extra zeros.

Comment: Can you explain what `temp.length()` does? Also, this is a *great* example where learning to use a debugger (set a breakpoint on the `int[]` line) will help you gain great enlightment

Comment: The default value of a `int` value in a `int array` is `0`

Comment: temp.length gives the length of the array in front.

Comment: You have `i += 2` - so `i` only traverses the even numbers.  That means you're only ever setting the even-numbered spots in the array.

Comment: `System.out.printf("length is %d%n", "1 3 5 7 6".length());`

Comment: i +=2 should work. I'll try changing it
Edit: It didn't change anything

Comment: *temp.length gives the length of the array* **WRONG** `temp` is a String

Comment: @LouisGuo chrylis asked the question to be Socratic, not because he/she didn't know.  Think about what he/she asked, and its significance to your problem.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem sorry. temp.length is meant to loop the for loop until all the numeric values (excluding the spaces) to the array. That's why there's "i += 2" and not "i = i + 2"

Comment: `i+=2` is the exact same thing as `i = i+2`

Comment: Louis Guo, did you even read my comment?  You're only setting the even-numbered spots in the array.

Comment: Can you explain why you are only assigning to every second element? and what value you expect the skipped elements to have? and how the actual values differ from your expectations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using character conversion in a way that only works with single digit numbers, it's fragile in a number of ways. Instead, split the `String` on whitespace and then parse those tokens. Like,

```
String temp = "1 3 5 7 6";
String[] tokens = temp.split("\\s+");
int[] array1 = new int[tokens.length];
for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
    array1[i] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[i]);
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array1));
```

Outputs (as I think you expected)

```
[1, 3, 5, 7, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

> Here issue in this line `temp.length()`. It will return `9` as a `string` length. As you know java takes default value `0`. That's why you are getting extra zeros.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Q1102 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String temp = "1 3 5 7 6";
    int length = (temp.length()  + 1)/2;
    int[] array1 = new int[length];
    for (int i = 0, k = 0; i < temp.length(); i +=2, k++) {
        int mounth = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(temp.charAt(i)));
        array1[k] = mounth;
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array1));

}
```